# Understanding MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I need help with the following MIPS code[image]

I am still confused about the way the stack pointer works to save the address of the current subroutine. Also, what happens after jal fact because it looks like this piece of code is never used since jal fact always updates the PC with the address of fact.

Comment: It would be better to copy/paste the text into a code block, instead of posting a picture of text.  That makes it un-searchable / un-indexable, and totally unusable to any blind users that use screen readers.  Your image doesn't have anything that wouldn't come through just fine in ASCII.

Comment: How do you create a code block?

Comment: ctrl-k.  Click the ? on the top right of the editor for formatting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrementing the stack pointer by a number reserves that many bytes of memory on the stack. Incrementing does the reverse, frees the space. Everything else about saving and restoring registers to/from the stack is provided in the comments.

The last instruction returns from the subroutine. Observe that there's a conditional branch to the end of the routine when the argument is zero. So, the recursive calls aren't infinite. Eventually the argument is decremented enough times to reach zero at which point the first return happens because the conditional branch jumps to the end of the subroutine. And then execution continues in the caller, after jal. After the multiplication, there's another return. And so on.